# How do we know that every halting Turing Machine can be expressed as a recursive function?

Tags: computer-science, computability, recursion

I've hear many times that a major result in Recursion Theory is the equivalence of Turing and Godel's models: the functions implementable on a Turing machine are precisely the functions that can be built from the [primitive recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) via composition and primitive recursion.

I am interested in the proof in the direction Turing $\to$ Godel.  How do we take a Turing machine and come up with a recursive definition of a function that is equivalent to the language decided by the Turing machine?

An explanation or a pointer to the paper(s) that prove this result would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There must be some confusion here, the set of primitive recursive functions is already closed under composition and (quite naturally) primitive recursion. Also _not all_ total recursive functions are primitive recursive, so you need to drop the "primitive", or modify your statement in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the proof in every mathematical book on recursion theory. The argument is roughly as follows:

1. If $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and the graph $\Gamma_f$ of $f$ is recursively enumerable then $f$ is recursive.
2. For every Turing Machine there is a unique Gödel number, which encodes the machine.
3. If $f$ is Turing then the graph is recursively enumerable. This is proofed by saying \begin{equation} (x,y) \in \Gamma_f \Leftrightarrow \exists s \in B_n(e,x_1,\ldots,x_n,y,s) \end{equation} where $B_n$ is the set of all $(e,x_1,\ldots,x_n,y,s) \in \mathbb{N}^{n+3}$ such that

   - $e$ is the Gödel number of the Machine $M$, $s$ is the Gödel number of the calculation of the machine $M$, the machine $M$ does $x_1,\ldots,x_n \to y$

   which is a primitive recursive set.
4. The claim follows from 1 and 3.

If you want more information for any of these steps, let me know.

EDIT: as Marc van Leeuwen pointed out in the comment above, this proves that Turing functions are recursive. The set of Turing functions is not the same as the set of *primitive* recursive functions.

Comment: The definition of your set $B_n$ wasn't displaying correctly (for me, at least).  As such I've made some formatting alterations (and hopefully zero content alterations).

Answer (score 1):

As @mjb says, this is an absolutely standard bookword result (at least when corrected by dropping "primitive").

You ask for pointers to the literature. For a proof-sketch slightly amplifying that @mjb gives, you could try my *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*, §32.3 in the first edition, §42.3 in the new, turbo-charged, retina-screen, improved CPU, generally whizzier, second edition ...